# iPhone app update using a different developer account

Tags: iphone, submission

I have an app which is available in app store and was signed with a certificate made from an account A. Now can I submit an update of the same app this time signing it with a different certificate created using another developer account say B?

Thanks in advance,
Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yes, but may be both developer account should be under same iPhone Developer Program Membership. Can you see the same application at http://itunesconnect.apple.com/ using another developer account?

Comment: My problem is both are different iPhone Developer Program membership

Comment: Then I suggest you to directly talk to Apple..
you can get contact number from http://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.html